# Find $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty b_n \sin(nx) = e^x$ for $0 < x < \pi$: Discrepancy Between Solutions.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, periodic-functions

I'm trying to find $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty b_n \sin(nx) = e^x$ for $0 < x < \pi$.

The domain of our problem is $[0, \pi]$, but as I understand it, the domain of Fourier series is $[-\pi, \pi]$ (or $[-L, L]$ in general). As I understand it, this, combined with the fact that we have a Fourier odd series, means that we need an odd extension of $e^x$.

So I defined

$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      e^x & 0 < x < \pi \\
      -e^{-x} & -\pi < x < 0 \\
   \end{cases}$

Continuing with my understanding, we get

$$b_n = \dfrac{2}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_0 e^x \sin(nx) \ dx + \dfrac{2}{\pi} \int^{0}_{-\pi} -e^{-x} \sin(nx) \ dx$$

**However**, after using an [online calculator](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B%5Cpi%7D%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cpi%7D%20e%5E%7Bx%7Dsin%5Cleft(nx%5Cright)dx%2B%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B%5Cpi%7D%5Cint_%7B-%5Cpi%7D%5E%7B0%7D%20-e%5E%7B-x%7Dsin%5Cleft(nx%5Cright)dx), this seems to be different from the solution my instructor provided:

> $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty b_n \sin(nx) = e^x$$
>
> $$\implies b_n = \dfrac{4n}{\pi(1 + n^2)},\ n\text{ odd.}$$

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this. Is there an error in my Fourier series calculation, or is the instructors solution erroneous?

Comment: Your $f$ is not odd, you should define $f$ as follows:$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      e^x & 0 < x < \pi \\
      -e^{-x} & -\pi< x < 0 \\
   \end{cases}$.

Comment: @FelixKlein Oops, you're absolutely correct. I will fix this. Thank you.

Comment: @FelixKlein Unfortunately, there still seems to be a discrepancy (refer to online calculator).

Comment: @MyGlasses What do you mean there is no difference? Are you saying that my solution is the same as the instructor's?

Comment: $$b_n = \dfrac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_0 e^x \sin(nx) \ dx + \dfrac{1}{\pi} \int^{0}_{-\pi} -e^{-x} \sin(nx) \ dx= \dfrac{2}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_0 e^x \sin(nx) \ dx$$

Comment: @MyGlasses Why is it $\dfrac{1}{\pi}$ instead of $\dfrac{2}{\pi}$?

Comment: @MyGlasses Ahh, I see: We have a period of period ($P$) $= 2 \pi$ for $$\dfrac{2}{P} \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + P} f(x) \sin \left( \dfrac{2 \pi n x}{P} \right) \ dx = \dfrac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) \sin(nx) \ dx = \dfrac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_0 e^x \sin(nx) \ dx + \dfrac{1}{\pi} \int^{0}_{-\pi} -e^{-x} \sin(nx) \ dx = \dfrac{2}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_0 e^x \sin(nx) \ dx$$

Comment: @MyGlasses But this is still different from the instructor's solution, is it not?

Comment: @MyGlasses $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty b_n \sin(nx) = e^x$$
$$\implies b_n = \dfrac{4n}{\pi(1 + n^2)},\ n\text{ odd.}$$

Comment: This is not the same as our solution of $b_n = \dfrac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi e^x \sin(nx) \ dx$

Comment: I get exactly the same answer, http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%2FPI%29integrate%28e%5Ex+sin%28nx%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2CPI%7D%29

Comment: Hmm, so the instructor's solution for $b_n$ is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, I think...

Comment: Thank you all for the assistance. I just received confirmation that the instructor's solution is incorrect. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{ \sin nx \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a complete orthogonal basis of functions for $L^2[0,\pi]$. So
$$
      e^{x} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{x}\sin nx dx}{\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^2 nx dx } \sin nx, \;\;\; a.e. x\in [0,\pi].
$$
And the two sides will agree everywhere except at the endpoints. The normalization constants are
\begin{align}
   \int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^2 nx dx 
    & = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^2 nx dx \\
    & = \frac{1}{4}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^2 nx + \cos^2 nx dx \\
    & = \frac{1}{4}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} dx = \frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{align}
And
\begin{align}
   \int_{0}^{\pi} e^{x}\sin nx dx & = \Im \int_{0}^{\pi}e^{x}e^{inx}dx \\
   & = \left.\Im \frac{1}{1+in}e^{x(1+in)}\right|_{x=0}^{\pi} \\
   & = \Im\frac{1-in}{1+n^2}((-1)^ne^{\pi}-1) \\
   & = \frac{n}{1+n^2}((-1)^{n+1}e^{\pi}+1)
\end{align}
So the orthogonal $\sin$ series that I get for $e^x$ on $[0,\pi]$ is
$$
      e^x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n}{\pi(1+n^2)}((-1)^{n+1}e^\pi+1)\sin nx.
$$